# Order collection by newest relationship model Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models `Chat` and `ChatMessage`.

`Chat` has many `ChatMessage`, i want to get all the `Chat` ordered by the `ChatMessage` `created_at`

So if the `created_at` of the `ChatMessage` has a date closest to today, that chat should be ordered first.

how could this be done?

I just have this

```
Chat::leftJoin('chat_messages', 'chats.id', '=', 'chat_messages.chat_id')
->orderBy('chat_messages.id', 'DESC');

but this does not work. i am not getting the newest row of chat_messages.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should order them by your `created_at` column:

```
$chats = Chat::select('chats.*')
    ->join('chat_messages', 'chats.id', '=', 'chat_messages.chat_id')
    ->orderBy('chat_messages.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

I've tested this with a database of 10 chats and 100 messages database where the last message has been created after the other ones and the last message is for the chat room with id #9.

So when I execute the code above and retrieve the first chat room, I get the following:

```
App\Chat { #3401
    id: 9,
    created_at: "2019-04-30 17:12:34",
    updated_at: "2019-04-30 17:12:34",
}
```

Comment: Cool, but that does not answer my question, i want to order ```Chats``` by the latest ```ChatMessage```

Comment: @CarlosSalazar Sorry I misread your question. Have a look at my update.

Comment: tried and did not work, the query does not order by the newest `ChatMessage` just get the first ChatMessage

Comment: `Chat::with('chat_messages')->orderBy('chat_messages.created_at, 'desc')->get();`

`chat_messages` - your has many relation